# Indirect formula to look up range of tabs

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble getting my indirect formula to work on a range of tabs.
I have 6 tabs between `IW` and `MP` which I want to sum up all of the cell `F23`s. I would like to have `IW:MP` (the range of tabs) in cell `F11` and indirectly refer to it.
So instead of having `=sum(IW:MP!F23)`, I would have `=sum(indirect(f11&"!f23"))` but I can't get it to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `=sum(IW:MP!F23)` should work for you, why to use indirect? https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/

Comment: I have lots of cells that need changing every time I add a new tab inside that range

Comment: @Foxfire And Burns And Burns 's formula takes that into account -- have you tried it?